# Rename index if nan

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have a df with index "Take_Make". Inside this index is one value with NaN. How can I rename this NaN to another "real" value, like "CatX" ?

df and df.index are shown below

```
df
Out[92]: 
           ParId  ParName  Resp
Take_Make                      
Cat1         194      194     0
Cat2         617      617     0
Cat3         379      379     0
NaN        11594    11594     1
```

```
df.index
Out[93]: CategoricalIndex(['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3', nan], categories=['Cat1', 'Cat2', 'Cat3'], ordered=False, dtype='category', name='Take_Make')
```

I tried some rename or replacing, but nothing happens. NaN or nan remains as it is.
Additional hint: The nan comes initially from a mysql database readout. This seems to be different from an original pandas nan value. Normally, a codeline like this works:

```
df.replace(np.nan,"CatX",inplace=True)
```

In this case, this doesn´t work.

Comment: Since it is a categorical index, you need to extend categories first: `df.index.add_categories([desired_value])`

Comment: Ok, means I have to add e.g. df_plot.index.add_categories('CatX').
But this is not persistant, and the change from NaN is still not done. Can you please explain bit more? @Marat
Thank you so much in advance

Comment: posted an answer

Comment: This works fine.
Imagine, I reset the index before with:
df = df.reset_index()
Is there also a (different) way? I tried then with df.fillna("CatX"), but got an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fill_category = 'CatX'
df.set_index(df.index.add_categories([fill_category]).fillna(fill_category))
```